# Renaming fields in new layer using MakeFeatureLayer?

Tags: arcpy, layers, fields-attributes

I have feature class that contains many fields.

I'm using MakeFeatureLayer tool in arcpy to make a new layer that would contain selected fields with different names.

Here's the code I've written to make the new layer:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("Firebreak","Firebreaks","","","OBJECTID OBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;FIREBREAKSUBTYPE TYPE VISIBLE NONE;SHAPE Shape VISIBLE NONE;FNUMBER FNUMBER HIDDEN NONE;GPSSATAVG GPSSATAVG HIDDEN NONE;GPSCOLLECTUSED GPSCOLLECTUSED HIDDEN NONE;SURVEYER SURVEYER HIDDEN NONE;GLOBALID GLOBALID HIDDEN NONE;LVMDISTRICTCODE LVMDISTRICTCODE HIDDEN NONE;BLOCKKEY BLOCKKEY HIDDEN NONE;LASTCHANGEAPP LASTCHANGEAPP HIDDEN NONE;LASTCHANGEDATE LASTCHANGEDATE HIDDEN NONE;SHAPE.LEN SHAPE_Leng VISIBLE NONE")
```

The new layer contains the fields I selected, but unfortunately, those fields aren't renamed, i.e., fields of new layer have the same names as fields in original layer.

How can I make MakeFeatureLayer to rename the fields of new layer?

Comment: What makes you think that the field name of the ***layer*** created has not been altered by MakeFeatureLayer from what is stored in the ***data***?

Comment: The new layer's attribute table's fields don't contain the desired field names and their types haven't changed. Or I just didn't understand the point of your question...

Comment: Your question only talks about renaming fields not altering field types.  I suspect that you are expecting MakeFeatureLayer to permanently alter a field name in your ***data*** whereas that tool will only change it in a layer which has that data as its source.  You may or may not be looking for the AlterField tool.

Answer (score 1):

[MakeFeatureLayer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-feature-layer.htm) only creates a temporary, in-memory layer. If you wish to save that layer to a file, then you would do something like:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("Firebreak","Firebreaks","","","OBJECTID OBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;FIREBREAKSUBTYPE TYPE VISIBLE NONE;SHAPE Shape VISIBLE NONE;FNUMBER FNUMBER HIDDEN NONE;GPSSATAVG GPSSATAVG HIDDEN NONE;GPSCOLLECTUSED GPSCOLLECTUSED HIDDEN NONE;SURVEYER SURVEYER HIDDEN NONE;GLOBALID GLOBALID HIDDEN NONE;LVMDISTRICTCODE LVMDISTRICTCODE HIDDEN NONE;BLOCKKEY BLOCKKEY HIDDEN NONE;LASTCHANGEAPP LASTCHANGEAPP HIDDEN NONE;LASTCHANGEDATE LASTCHANGEDATE HIDDEN NONE;SHAPE.LEN SHAPE_Leng VISIBLE NONE")

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management('Firebreaks', r'path\where\I\want\to\save.gdb\Firebreaks')
```

See [CopyFeatures](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-features.htm).

Also, as an alternative to the long field info string, you could use a [FieldInfo](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/fieldinfo.htm) object.